# Apply filter option in your html table

Tags: php, html

I want to apply filter to my html table for following:
   1. Search name/emailid
   2. Page Length (As my table has thousands of records)
Also, I want to give an option to update record where I enter name, all information should be autopopulated to that form and then user can update whatever he wants to.
Following is my code given:

```
        <?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = ''; // Password
$db_name = 'contacts'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM usait LIMIT 50' ;

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Displaying MySQL Data in HTML Table</title>
<style type="text/css">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
           <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    body { {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #343d44;
        font-family: "segoe-ui", "open-sans", tahoma, arial;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    table {
        margin: auto;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe Ui";
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 25px auto 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    table td {
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    /* Table */
    .data-table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 537px;
    }

    .data-table th, 
    .data-table td {
        border: 1px solid #e1edff;
        padding: 7px 17px;
    }
    .data-table caption {
        margin: 7px;
    }

    /* Table Header */
    .data-table thead th {
        background-color: #508abb;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-color: #6ea1cc !important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    /* Table Body */
    .data-table tbody td {
        color: #353535;
    }
    .data-table tbody td:first-child,
    .data-table tbody td:nth-child(4),
    .data-table tbody td:last-child {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .data-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
        background-color: #f4fbff;
    }
    .data-table tbody tr:hover td {
        background-color: #ffffa2;
        border-color: #ffff0f;
    }

    /* Table Footer */
    .data-table tfoot th {
        background-color: #e5f5ff;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .data-table tfoot th:first-child {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .data-table tbody td:empty
    {
        background-color: #ffcccc;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
   <table class="data-table" id="example">
    <caption class="title">US Data</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>ContactOwner</th>
            <th>LeadSource</th>
            <th>First_name</th>
            <th>Last_name</th>
            <th>AccountName</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>EmailID</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Industry</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Assistant</th>
            <th>AsstPhone</th>
            <th>ReportsTo</th>
            <th>LinkedIn</th>
            <th>CallStatus</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>OtherStreet</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $no     = 1;
    $total  = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {

        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['ContactOwner'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['LeadSource'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['First_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Last_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['AccountName'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Title'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['EmailID'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Department'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Industry'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Phone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Mobile'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Fax'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['DOB'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Assistant'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['AsstPhone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['ReportsTo'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['LinkedIn'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['CallStatus'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Street'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['OtherStreet'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['City'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['State'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Zip'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Country'].'</td>    
                <td>'.$row['Description'].'</td>                    
            </tr>';

        $no++;
    }?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="26">TOTAL</th>
            <th><?=number_format($total)?></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
 </table>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
} );
} );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of code to implement these filters? Are you trying to implement them via AJAX or just through the frontend (e.g. JS filtering the table for you?)

Comment: I don't know ho to do it and that is why I have posted a question here how to do that.

Comment: @Optimae : I have updated the code by adding js code into it.Can you please check once and let me know .It is showing 50 records per page but there is no option to go to next page.

Comment: You need a table with lot of content and you need to do pagination if it exceeds certain amount of contents. Is this is your need?

Comment: @ManiRaj: I already have table which has thousands of records for now and I want to display 100records per page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) feature of [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) instead of rendering inside HTML. With server-side processing able to handle large data sets. Also other features will be work like a charm filtering, searching, pagination etc. as you want.

DataTables provide [simple example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) for this. Frontend and server-side scripts are both available, you have to just configure your MySQL connection and will be ready to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ugur.I will try using it and will let you know.

Comment: I have added that code from DataTables ,but still it is not working.Can you please tell me if that code is right and enough or do I need to add links which are shared in that page.

Comment: You can find more code examples with data samples from their GitHub repository. https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/tree/master/examples/server_side/scripts

Comment: Can you please check code once and let me know if it is correct.Added CSS,JS .

Comment: You need to user whole files. In frontend, point server-side PHP script location as AJAX resource like example in answer, then configure PHP script for your database. In the end you will get a PHP file responses JSON output for DataTables and on your frontend gets data from that file.

Comment: This sounds little confusing to me but I will definitely try it step by step and will get back to you.